# How to animate meshes moving on a rail and export to UE5

Tags: animation, armature

I'm playing around with how to animate meshes moving on a rail and export/bake this animation for UE5.

In this example I have a path, an armature with two bones and the mesh.
The large bone has a Follow Path Bone Constraint. The second one has a Follow Path Bone Constraint and a Damped Track looking at the first bone.
The mesh is weighted to the second bone.
This kinda works, I can export to FBX and use the animation in UE5, but is a bit annoying to set up.
Can I somehow make this simpler with only one bone?

[image]

But what I actually need, is a mesh like this.
So here I just created a cube and added an Array modifier and a Curve modifier.
This is not ideal, as the Curve modifier deforms the mesh, I don't want that.
Also I can't export this, as it has no keyframes.
How do I set this up with an armature and keyframe it?
Creating one bone for each piece would be really annoying.

[image]